# Change geometry on first page

Tags: fancyhdr, geometry, everypage

I want to generate a document which has a header and footer on the first page but only a footer on all other pages. I used `fancyhdr` for the header, I have a general header style and one for the first page which uses `\thispagestyle`. This works fine.

My problem is that the page does not change its geometry. The `\textheight` keeps its old height, how do I change it?

I wrote a little example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

% packages
\usepackage[includeheadfoot, heightrounded, left=2cm, right=2cm, top=5mm, bottom=1cm, headheight=5.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% only to show header and footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1px}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1px}

% header and footer for first page
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{
    \fancyhead[L]{%
        Header \\ for \\ the \\ first \\ page \\ wTestch \\ is \\ really \\ big
    }
    \fancyfoot[C]{Footer}
}
% all other pages
\fancypagestyle{normal}{
    \fancyfoot[C]{Footer Only}
}
\pagestyle{normal}

% try to change the style for all pages that have a smaller header
\AddEverypageHook{
    \ifnum\value{page}=1%
    \else
        % removes the header space but pushes everytTestng upwards
        \newgeometry{includeheadfoot, heightrounded, left=2cm, right=2cm, top=5mm, bottom=1cm, headheight=.5cm, footskip=-5.5cm}%
        \enlargethispage*{5cm} % does not work
        \setlength{\textheight}{\dimexpr(\textheight+5cm)} % does not work
        \addtolength{\textheight}{5cm} % does not work
    \fi
}

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{firstpage}
    Test
    \newpage
    Test

    ...
\end{document}
```

The in the resulting document (on page 2) you can see that the textheight is not increasing:[image: Result of the example code, page 2 shows that the textheight is not big enough.]

Site note: The LaTeX code is generated via a program so I do not know where the new page is inserted, neigther where the first page ends nor where other page breaks are. Also I cannot control the page breaks because the contents of the document is changing dynamically.

I hope somebody can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup the normal page layout and use \vspace* on the first page to move the text down. To avoid that fancyhdr enlarges the header you must hide the height of the large header:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

% packages
\usepackage[includeheadfoot, heightrounded, left=2cm, right=2cm, top=5mm, bottom=1cm, headheight=.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% only to show header and footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1px}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1px}

% header and footer for first page
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{
    \fancyhead[L]{% hide height of header
        \raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}Header \\ for \\ the \\ first \\ page \\ wTestch \\ is \\ really \\ big\end{tabular}}
    }
    \fancyfoot[C]{Footer}
}
% all other pages
\fancypagestyle{normal}{
    \fancyfoot[C]{Footer Only}
}
\pagestyle{normal}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{firstpage}\vspace*{5cm}
    \lipsum \lipsum
    %\newpage
    Test

    ...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your suggestion works and I will use it (and check it as the correct answer) if there is no better solution. You cannot know that but the problem **for me** is that it is not too simple to implement the changings in the header and document contents caused by the way the code is generated.