# Restoregeometry causes text to run of page

Tags: geometry, afterpage

Currently, I am working on a package for an association. I am trying to achieve the following: the geometry of the first page should be different from all the following pages. There are some questions answered that achieve exactly what I want, however, when I try to use these answers myself, they do not seem to actually work.

From [Question 449245](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/449245/can-i-make-the-geometry-of-the-first-page-different-from-other-pages), the following code:

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    top=3cm,
    hmargin=1in,
}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\begin{document}
\newgeometry{top=8cm}
\afterpage{\aftergroup\restoregeometry}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

The question provides exactly what I want to achieve, but the provided solution does not actually work for me:[image: text still running of the page]

Does anybody know why this solution does not work anymore? Is there a way to fix the code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is that the big paragraph in page 2 will trigger the page breaking mechanism too late for `\restoregeometry` to enter into action, so the second page is built with conflicting page parameters. If your need is because of a different header in the first page, this can be accommodated in different ways. The `\afterpage` command works when it does, which unfortunately isn't always.

Comment: both `\restoregeomety` and (especially) `\afterpage` are far more fragile than you need here and `\afterpage{\aftergroup\restoregeometry}` with an `\aftergroup` does the restore at an essentially unknown point. Why do you need to change the geometry at all compared to simply using `\vspace*{...}` to adjust the start on the first page?

Comment: is this a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/420324/1090

Answer (score 0):

After trying a bit more, I found that using `\globaldefs=1` instead of `\aftergroup` seemed to resolve any issues I still faced.

Comment: I doubt that `\restoregeometry` has ever been tested with `\globaldefs=1` it might possibly work in some cases but any behaviour would be undefined, it certainly isn't supported by the package.

Comment: Sorry, but `\globaldefs=1` is a very dangerous way of living.

Comment: Any suggestions for a more reliable way then `\globaldefs=1` to achieve the intended goal?

Comment: @G.deMan as far as I can guess from the code you show you just want 5cm of white space on the first page, so you do not need `geometry` at all, simply something like `\AtBeginDocument{\vspace*{5cm}}` see Ulrike's answer in the link I put under the question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle sadly the actual document is a bit more complicated than that. The MWE just shows the wanted behaviour, a simple space does not suffice in the final document.

Comment: @G.deMan all  newgeometry can do is change the top and  bottom margin, it can't do and complicated typesetting, and there are almost no cases where you need newgeometry to do that on the first page. I wrote `\afterpage` and I'd think twice about  using it in production. I wrote (in 1993)  in the package manual : "This is really a pre-release, to see whether people like the idea of a command like this. This implementation is \emph{not} particularly robust. This implementation does not work in two column mode, and can get `confused' by \LaTeX's floating environments."  the code has not changed.